# Bookmarks toolbar in Firefox 29?

Tags: firefox, bookmarks

I love to have my favorite bookmarks (bookmarklets, and so on) on my firefox toolbar, but, surprise, in firefox 29 the toolbar is empty. I tried to use classic look restorer toolbar, but still the bookmarks toolbar is empty. When I add a new bookmark, I select "bookmark toolbar", but still is not shown on the toolbar.

Should I wipe my firefox profile and try again (ugh, no, please), or it's because the firefox ui team decided that nobody likes toolbar?

EDIT: I have the same problem at work, but here I don't have the permissions to uninstall and reinstall!!

What can I do???

I can't just wipe my profile, because I must set up Firefox Sync in the classic way, that means I have to set up in Firefox<28 and then upgrade.

When I drag bookmarks to the bookmarks tab, I get the forbidden icon (I took a photo because with a screenshot it doesn't show it)

[image: doesnt work]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution! For some reason, after upgrading to Firefox 29, the bookmark toolbar was missing the "bookmark items" and this was spread to all my browsers via Firefox Sync.

I just reset all the toolbars by pressing "customize" and then "reset toolbars to default":
[image: so easy...]

Answer (score 0):

1. You want to see the FF bookmark bar on your FF browser, but it doesn't show?
2. Have you tried right-click on title of FF window, then select Bookmarks Toolbar as photo below:
   [image]
3. After that, If you can't see it, you should re-install FF.

Good luck!

Comment: I'm doing exactly that, but it doesn't show my bookmarks... it's just empty...

Comment: Have you checked your bookmark folder? Are there any bookmark items? Another way, you can open the Bookmarks sidebar (Ctrl+B) and drag your  item bookmarked (HTML file) to the Bookmarks Toolbar

Comment: No, dragging did not show them. I had to uninstall and re-install :(

Comment: At work I can't uninstall firefox, what can I do??? Also I can't just wipe my profile, because they changed the way firefox sync works, and if I update, I lose sync with firefox 23 on my phone (higher version of firefox on my phone crashes at boot)